# Change css of class when select radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a image with the css class `.normalImage` 
I made 3 radio buttons and when the user select 1 of the radio buttons the style of the image must change to `.blackImage` or `.sepiaImage`

I have 3 radio buttons, each must activate a new style to the image :

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="grijs">Black<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="sepia">Sepia<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="normal">Normaal<br>
```

How can i change the style of the image when someone checks one of the radio buttons?

Comment: I think this will give you the answer you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152927/how-to-use-radio-on-change-event

Comment: Can you re-use the `name` attribute like that? Just curious.

Comment: @Paulie_D why not..? in my knowledge that's how you make a radio button group...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2JC8R/

Comment: @TJ What I meant was, shouldn't they be like ID's and unique? I confess, I don't know. EDIT: aha - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518458/does-a-name-attribute-have-to-be-unique-in-a-html-document

Comment: Your question is not clear. "must change to .blackImage or .sepiaImage" are you applying classes randomly..? or do you need to apply a specific class for a specific radio..?

Comment: @Paulie_D the purpose of common `name` attribute here is to group them together so that only one among them can be selected at a time.. if the names are different all 3 can be selected at a time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method

Try this :

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {    
    $("img").removeClass();
    if($(this).val() == "grijs"){   
        $('img').addClass('blackImage');
    }
    else if($(this).val() == "sepia"){
        $('img').addClass('sepiaImage');
    }
    else if($(this).val() == "normal"){
        $('img').addClass('normalImage');
    }
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/feTJ3/)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
$('input[name=color]').on('click', function() {
    $('#my-image').removeClass().addClass( $(this).val()+"Image" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a click function with parameter off the css class.

```
   function setCssClass(className){
        $("#IMAGE_ID").addClass(className);
   }

   <input type="radio" name="color" value="grijsImage" onclick="setCssClass('grijs');">Black<br>
   <input type="radio" name="color" value="sepiaImage" onclick="setCssClass('sepiaImage');">Sepia<br>
   <input type="radio" name="color" value="normal"onclick="setCssClass('normal');">Normaal<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, addClass()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ("input[type='radio']")  
      { 
 $(this).addClass("newclass");
      }
</script>
```

if you wish to remove the previous class then you can use:

```
if ("input[type='radio']")  
      { 
 $(this).removeClass().addClass("newclass");            
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle radio button .change() event and check for selected and deselected. After that use .removeClass() and .addClass() methods.

Answer (score 0):

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QUfy3/1/)

jQuery:

```
var $img = $("#myImage");

$('input[name=color]').on('change', function() {
   $img.removeClass().addClass($(this).val());
});
```

HTML:

```
<p id="myImage">Text instead of an image</p>

<input type="radio" name="color" value="grijs">Black<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="sepia">Sepia<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="normal">Normaal<br>
```

CSS:

```
.grijs {
    color: red;
}

.sepia {
    color: blue;
}

.normal {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to change the class; rather than removing then adding a new class, you could use the [jQuery `switchClass()` function.](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/)

Like this:

```
var $img = $("#myImage");

$('input[name=color]').on('change', function()
{
   $img.switchClass($img.attr('class'), $(this).val());
});
```