# JavaScript Prevent text entry if it does not meet parameters

Tags: javascript, html

When working with a JavaScript function I want to prevent characters from being entered into a form if they do not meet certain parameters. The original JavaScript code I used was:

```js
    function validateLetter() {
        var textInput = document.getElementById("letter").value;
        var replacedInput = textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");
        if(textInput != replacedInput)
            alert("You can only enter letters into this field.");

        document.getElementById("letter").value = replacedInput;
  }
```

That function worked while I was using only 1 input point in my form, however when I tried to use that function over multiple inputs it would only affect the first one in the form.

When creating a function that could be reused by multiple input boxes I got the following code:

```js
function validateLetter(dataEntry){
 try {
     var textInput = dataEntry.value;
            var replacedInput = textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g);
            if (textInput != replacedInput)
                throw "You can only enter letters into this field.";

 }
 catch(InputError) {
  window.alert(InputError)
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

The form I am using to input information is:

```html
<form action="validateTheCharacters" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <p>Enter your mother's maiden name:
    <input type="text" id="letter" name="letter" onkeypress="validateLetter();" />
  </p>
  <p>Enter the city you were born in:
    <input type="text" id="letter" name="letter" onkeypress="validateLetter();" />
  </p>
  <p>Enter the street you grew up on:
    <input type="text" id="letter" name="letter" onkeypress="validateLetter()">
  </p>
</form>
```

Does anyone know a way to translate the last line of the first function: document.getElementById("letter").value = replacedInput;

To something that can be re-used with the current code.

I tried:
dataEntry.value = replacedInput
But that did not seem to run/change the function at all

Comment: Since you tagged `HTML5`, have you considered `<input pattern="[^A-Za-z]">`?

Comment: Your text inputs all have the same id, and you use id to get the element, only the first element get by "document.getElementById("letter")", that's why only the first text input can work.

Comment: I looked into using <input pattern="[^A-Za-z]"> but that only prevents the data from being submitted when it doesn't meet parameters, I want to prevent invalid characters from being entered into the box at all

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `textInput.replace()` - you forgot the second parameter. So instead of `textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g);`, you need `textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id):

> The ID must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the element using getElementById.

In your example above, you are using the same value for the ID attribute on all of the input fields. Also, the **name** attribute should be unique within forms. The answer provided [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518458/does-a-name-attribute-have-to-be-unique-in-a-html-document) explains in greater depth. With that said, in the examples below I have modified your input fields in respect to the above.

---

First off, the initial function you provided was pretty close. One issue with it is that the **replace()** method would need a second parameter. This parameter can be a string or a function to be called for each match. In your case I believe you just want an empty string:

```
function validateLetter() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("letter").value;
    var replacedInput = textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");
    if(textInput != replacedInput)
        alert("You can only enter letters into this field.");

    document.getElementById("letter").value = replacedInput;
}
```

Secondly, you can reference the current input field that is invoking **validateLetter()** by passing it along to the function as a parameter using the keyword `this`.

`onkeypress="validateLetter(this);"`

*On a sidenote: You might achieve a better user experience using `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`. The example below utilizes this event instead so you can compare and judge for yourself.*

Here is everything put together in a working example:

```js
function validateLetter(target) {
    var textInput = target.value;
    var replacedInput = textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");
    if(textInput != replacedInput)
        alert("You can only enter letters into this field.");

    target.value = replacedInput;
}
```

```html
<form action="validateTheCharacters" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <p>Enter your mother's maiden name:
    <input type="text" id="maiden" name="maiden" onkeyup="validateLetter(this);" />
  </p>
  <p>Enter the city you were born in:
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" onkeyup="validateLetter(this);" />
  </p>
  <p>Enter the street you grew up on:
    <input type="text" id="street" name="street" onkeyup="validateLetter(this)">
  </p>
</form>
```