# Laravel checkbox macro with forced values

Tags: php, html, laravel, checkbox

I'm trying to post 0 for unchecked and 1 for checked checkboxes.

**macros.php**

```
Form::macro("check", function($name, $value = 1, $checked = null, $options = array()){
    return Form::hidden($name, 0).Form::checkbox($name, $value, $checked, $options);
});
```

Its html output in browser:

```
<input name="mycheckbox" value="0" type="hidden">
<input id="mycheckboxID" name="mycheckbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

I submit the form, it returns 1 for checked and 0 for unchecked.

**Problem :** When i post and `return dd(Input::get('mycheckbox'));` 
it sometimes returns me the actual values like 0 for unchecked 1 for checked, but sometimes it returns me the wrong values like 0 for checked and 1 for unchecked. Any ideas ?

Comment: Your checkbox and your hidden input both share the same `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox and your hidden input both share the same `name` attribute. Also the checkbox will only contain a value if actually checked.

Use different names and it should work as expected.

Comment: then can you please tell me how am i supposed to get the values of a checkbox named differently in my controller with Input::get('fieldname'); ?

Comment: You *can* have multiple checkboxes that share the same name. That's alright. You will then get an array of the clicked values using `Input::get('fieldname');` But you cannot have checkboxes AND hidden inputs with the same `name` attribute.

Comment: i'm doing the same thing for radio buttons and it works nicely, interesting. So, assume that i have changed the hidden field name. Input::get('fieldname') returns the string value of that field. not an array.

Comment: Maybe this will help to make things clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518458/does-a-name-attribute-have-to-be-unique-in-a-html-document

Comment: I read everything on that post and did not help. My way is working smoothly, found out there was a problem with my Model::updateOrCreate() method. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: I still wonder how it could work with text inputs and checkboxes having the same name attribute. Anyway I'm glad you solved it. Cheers.