# JQuery finding the name of the next input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7owh3rs0/)

I have the following, three sets of checkboxes:

```
<h3 class="heading">List 1 <span><a id="list1" href="javascript:;">check all</a></span></h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list1[]" value="3" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list1[]" value="4" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list1[]" value="5" /> Option 3</label><br />
<h3 class="heading">List 2 <span><a id="list2" href="javascript:;">check all</a></span></h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list2[]" value="3" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list2[]" value="4" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list2[]" value="5" /> Option 3</label><br />
<h3 class="heading">List 3 <span><a id="list3" href="javascript:;">check all</a></span></h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list3[]" value="3" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list3[]" value="4" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list3[]" value="5" /> Option 3</label><br />
```

And with JQuery, I'm trying to get it so when a "check all" link is clicked, it dynamically finds the next `input` name:

```
$('#list1, #list2, #list3').on('click', function () {
    var allChecked = true;
    var inputName = $(this).next('label > input:checkbox').attr('name');
    console.log(inputName);
    inputName.each(function() {
        if (!this.checked) {
            allChecked = false;
        }
    });
    inputName.prop('checked', !allChecked);
});
```

The problem is all of my attempts to find the next `input` name fails, and the console returns: `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read the doco for the `.next()` method? It finds only the immediate next *sibling* (if there is one matching the selector), it doesn't just generally search on through the DOM.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, it's not just `next()`... I've tried `nextAll()`, `find()`, etc...

Comment: Is the goal to find the next name, or to just check/uncheck the related elements? Both can be done, but you don't really need to search for the name, because it is the same as the clicked element's ID except with `[]` on the end.

Comment: You may have to implement a more sophisticated means of targeting them than relying on built-in jQuery methods.  Also, it might be problematic that you have so many duplicated `name` attributes...

Comment: @anied - Nothing wrong with duplicated `name`s. They have different values.

Comment: I would recommend better formatting of the HTML to group relevant stuff together. I could reorganise it if you would like

Comment: @nnnnnn -- yeah, just [spotted that myself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518458/does-a-name-attribute-have-to-be-unique-in-a-html-document), was coming back to correct myself.

Comment: @nnnnnn the goal is both, to find the next name so I can check/uncheck the related elements. The ID in this example is simplified to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.next()` method finds only the immediate next sibling (if there is one matching the selector), it doesn't just generally search on through the DOM.

<s>But you don't need to use DOM navigation to find the elements that follow, because the `id` of the clicked element is directly related to the `name` of the associated checkboxes.</s>

Apparently the `id` -> `name` relationship doesn't exist in your *real* code. OK, then I'd suggest the best method would be to add a `data-associated-cb="list1[]"` attribute to the checkbox so that you can just read that attribute instead of doing DOM navigation. That way it doesn't matter if the structure changes, the elements would still be linked. Or use a common class. Whatever.

But if you still *really* just want to do DOM navigation for exactly the structure shown you can do this to get all of the checkboxes:

```
$(this).closest('h3').nextUntil('h3').find(':checkbox')
```

...or for just the first one:

```
$(this).closest('h3').next().find(':checkbox')
```

So, slotting that into your existing code, you get this:

```js
$('#list1, #list2, #list3').on('click', function(e) {
  var allChecked = true;
  var inputName = $(this).closest('h3').nextUntil('h3').find(':checkbox');
  inputName.each(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
      allChecked = false;
    }
  });
  inputName.prop('checked', !allChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="heading">List 1 <span><a id="list1" href="javascript:;">check all</a></span></h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list1[]" value="3" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list1[]" value="4" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list1[]" value="5" /> Option 3</label><br />
<h3 class="heading">List 2 <span><a id="list2" href="javascript:;">check all</a></span></h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list2[]" value="3" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list2[]" value="4" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list2[]" value="5" /> Option 3</label><br />
<h3 class="heading">List 3 <span><a id="list3" href="javascript:;">check all</a></span></h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list3[]" value="3" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list3[]" value="4" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list3[]" value="5" /> Option 3</label><br />
```

Note that you can simplify your function (you don't need the `.each()`):

```
$('#list1, #list2, #list3').on('click', function(e) {
  var inputName = $(this).closest('h3').nextUntil('h3').find(':checkbox');
  inputName.prop('checked', inputName.filter(":checked").length < inputName.length);
});
```

Comment: I do need the name... As stated in the comments, the ID in my example code is simplified on purpose to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Updated with a shorter version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet. Since you used the name attribute and its similar with the ID of the triggering element.

```js
$('#list1,#list2,#list3').click(function() {
  $('input[name="' + $(this).attr('id') + '[]"]').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="heading">List 1 <span><a id="list1" href="javascript:;">check all</a></span></h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list1[]" value="3" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list1[]" value="4" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list1[]" value="5" /> Option 3</label><br />
<h3 class="heading">List 2 <span><a id="list2" href="javascript:;">check all</a></span></h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list2[]" value="3" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list2[]" value="4" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list2[]" value="5" /> Option 3</label><br />
<h3 class="heading">List 3 <span><a id="list3" href="javascript:;">check all</a></span></h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list3[]" value="3" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list3[]" value="4" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="list3[]" value="5" /> Option 3</label><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please check the code for get value.
$('#list1,#list2,#list3').click(function() {
  var idName = $(this).attr('id')+'[]';
  $("input[name='"+idName+"']").each( function () {
     alert( $(this).val() );
  });
});
```