# Input radio button value returns nothing in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm trying to pass value of `dataquery1` to a servlet but it returns nothing.
Here is my code in jsp :

```html
<form id="formquery" action="queryD" method="post">
  <div>Search for : &nbsp;&nbsp; 

        <select id="option" class="enjoy-css" style="width:170px" name="optdata">                       
    <option>Choose options</option>
    <option value="scname">Scientific Name</option>                     
    <option value="fname">Family Name</option>
      <option value="location">Location</option>
      <option value="wateruse">Water Usage</option>
    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input class="enjoy-css" type="submit" name="Search" value="Search">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a style="text-decoration: underline" onclick="resetQuery()">Reset</a><br/>
    <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <div id="opt1" style="display:none;">
    Keyword : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input class="enjoy-css" style="width:120px" placeholder="Enter keyword" type="text" name="dataquery1">
    <br><br>    
    </div>

    <br/>
    <div id="opt2" style="display:none;">
    <input type="radio" name="dataquery1" value="DTC"> DTC<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dataquery1" value="Engineering"> Engineering<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dataquery1" value="Business"> Business<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dataquery1" value="Science"> Science<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dataquery1" value="Law"> Law<br>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <div id="opt3" style="display:none;">
    <input type="radio" name="dataquery1" value="Low"> Low<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dataquery1" value="Low to moderate"> Low to moderate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dataquery1" value="Moderate to high"> Moderate to high<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dataquery1" value="High"> High<br>
    </div>

  </div>
  </form>
```

And here is in my servlet

```js
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  System.out.println("queryD.java");

  //get query from newquery.jsp
  String dataquery1 = "";
  dataquery1 = request.getParameter("dataquery1");

  //get option from newquery.jsp
  String optdata = "";
  optdata = request.getParameter("optdata");

  System.out.println("OPTDATA : " + optdata + " | KEYWORD : " + dataquery1 + ".");
```

For `opt1` div, it works perfectly. But for `opt2` and `opt3` it returns nothing. I tried to change from radio input to text input but it still doesn't work.

PS: `opt1, opt2, opt3` display is set to `none` but i have the function that call for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in my own IDE and reproduced your problem. The problem is this. Your checkboxes and 1 text input all have the same name attribute, so when you send this to your servlet, what you get is an **array of elements ("dataquery1")**!

if you leave the "keyword" input empty, you will see nothing when you try and access it via the servlet. Because **you are trying to access a String value when you need to access the array**. If you do not leave the "keyword" input empty and try to get the String value of "dataquery1", you will automatically get the first value of the array.

**Your form:**
[image: your form]

**The network tab to debug (to see what gets sent): **
[image: network tab in html inspect]

To access your variables you have to use an array. (because "dataquery1" is not unique") Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518458/does-a-name-attribute-have-to-be-unique-in-a-html-document) for further information on that.

Here is how you do it:

```
String[] test = request.getParameterValues("dataquery1");
String value1 = test[0];
String value2 = test[1];
```

[image: ide test]

Comment: Okay, but I need the `dataquery1` to be a string as I cannot access it as array for other use (more complicated work later). What if I rename the 2nd and 3rd radiobox with different name? Does it still consider as an array as well?

Comment: Then you need to use unique name attributes. Or just change your keyword input name attribute to something else. Then you will be able to access the checkboxes normally.

Answer (score 0):

You have given same name to both radio buttons in two different divs. Give one name to all the radios of first div and another name to second div.