# Fetching Radio button value from dynamic table

Tags: html, jsp, html-table, radio-button

In a JSP page, I have a dynamic table with one of its columns being a radio button. The contents of the table are defined.

```
  <c:forEach items="${portSwapMappingList}" var="portSwapMapping">

<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${portSwapMapping.portSwapBean.sourceNodeName}"/></td> 
    <td><c:out value="${portSwapMapping.portSwapBean.sourcePortName}"/></td> 
    <td><c:out value="${portSwapMapping.portSwapBean.targetNodeName}"/></td> 
    <td><c:out value="${portSwapMapping.portSwapBean.targetPortName}"/></td> 
    <td><c:out value="${portSwapMapping.portSwapBean.swapType}"/></td> 
    <td> <input type="radio" property="radioButton" name="selectradio" value="${portSwapMapping.portSwapBean.sourcePortName}"/>  </td> 
    <td><c:out value="${portSwapMapping.migrationStepStatusMap}"/></td> 

</tr>
```

Here, when I create the radio button, I'm setting the value that I'm setting in the second column of my dynamic table. You could consider this to be a primary key.

Now, on the click of a submit button, my web application is using the method `request.getParameter(selectradio)` to identify the radio button which is selected but the value retrieved by the method is null.

I have tried using all possible options, but without any success. Even if I provide a hard-coded value while populating the table, the result returned is null.

However, if I created a single row and fetched the value, it was correctly retrieved.

Appreciate if anyone could help out with this.

Comment: Presumably all your radio buttons have the same name? If that's the case then you will have to get an Array from the request, not a string.

Comment: Yes. I have to set the same name to the radio button to allow selection of just one of the button. Do you mean I retrieve the value as String[] value = request.getParameter(selectradio).

Comment: yes, check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134630/input-radio-button-value-returns-nothing-in-servlet/46135381#46135381