# React elements with same name

Tags: reactjs

I have a little dumb question, but in react does elements having the same `name` can create problems and/or is considered as bad pratice ? I know that is the case for `id` but I don't know if the same can be applied for `name`.

An example would be the name with value "ID" of the following code:

```
Class App extends Component{

  render(){
    <div className="App">
      <input name="ID" id="order-ID" type="text">
     <input name="ID" id="products-ID" type="text">
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share an example of source code?

Comment: Do you mean you are creating _React components_ that share the same name when declared, or do you mean that you have mark-up in which multiple elements are being given 'name' attributes with identical values?

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk Ok !

Comment: @AlexanderNied I'm talking about the case where I have mark-up in which multiple elements are being given 'name' attributes with identical values. I just made an example

Comment: So you're talking about [the `name` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name), which makes this more of an HTML question than a ReactJS question, one which probably has [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518458/does-a-name-attribute-have-to-be-unique-in-a-html-document).