# How to select checkbox by name

Tags: html, css, selenium

I'm struggling to get proper css (or any pother) locator for my checkbox. There are two on the page with same attributes by different text, I don't know how to build working selector. I want to avoid using index. I want to select them by `'Name1'` and `'Name2'`
Here are the attributes:

```
<label>
<input class="some class name" name="checkOptions" type="checkbox">Name1
</label>

<label>
<input class="some class name" name="checkOptions" type="checkbox">Name2
</label>
```

Comment: 'by different names' --> They have the same name?

Comment: sorry, I meant 'displayed text', not the attribute 'name' (corrected)

Comment: Maybe something like this: "(//input[text()='Name1'])"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: If you could have used script it could be `[...document.querySelectorAll("label")]
  .filter(label => label.textContent.trim() === "Name2")[0]
  .querySelector("input").checked = true`

Comment: BTW: Please consider reading: [Does a name attribute have to be unique in a HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518458/does-a-name-attribute-have-to-be-unique-in-a-html-document).

Answer (score 1):

If the only uniqueness of the elements is their texts you have to locate them according to that texts.
Try this `xpath`:  `//input[contains(text(),'Name1')]` for the first and `//input[contains(text(),'Name2')]` for the second element.
In case you need to add more uniqueness you can add the class name or any other attribute like following:
`//input[@class='some class name' and contains(text(),'Name1')]` and
`//input[@class='some class name' and contains(text(),'Name2')]`

Comment: this one doesn't return any locator, NoSuchElementException

Comment: What `xpath` did you try? Are you sure 'Name1' is text and not a value? Did you give enough delay before searching for the element?

Comment: Also, I hope you are using a correct `By` i.e. `driver.findElements(By.xpath(//input[contains(text(),'Name1')]));`

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, the text is inside label (*...and outside input...*).

Well, possible alternative is use css ":contains" selector

```
  $("label:contains('Name1')").css('background-color', 'red');
```

For get input:

```
  $("label:contains('Name1') > input")
```

Consider this native function is case sensitive.
Alternative can create custom function:

```
$.expr[':'].containsCaseIns = function(a, i, m) {
  return $(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

$("label:containsCaseIns('Name1') > input")
```